# .live() to .on() issue

Tags: jquery

I have a problem that can not solve.

This code works perfect for me.

```
// click row opens message, unless you click delete    
$('.delete_message-link-js').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.item-message').live('click', function(e){ //.item-message - tr lass
    window.location = $(this).find(".show_message-link").attr("href");
});
```

But when i change **.live()** to **.on()**

```
// click row opens message, unless you click delete
$('.delete_message-link-js').on('click', false );

$('.item-message').on('click', function(e){
     window.location = $(this).find(".show_message-link").attr("href");
  });
```

i have a bug in Firefox . When I click at .delete_message-link-js link in table row  i get a error

> prompt aborted by user 
>   throw Components.Exception...by user", Cr.NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE);

But code works in Safari.

What i doing  wrong?

Thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: Are the `.delete_message-link-js` links added dynamically after the page has loaded?

Comment: can you please make a `fiddle `for understanding better on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 9):

Read the documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

From there we can see that the `on` equivalent of this:

```
$('.delete_message-link-js').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

is:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".delete_message-link-js", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

And so on.

You could also read the source code to see how `live` is transformed into `on`:

```
live: function( types, data, fn ) {
    jQuery( this.context ).on( types, this.selector, data, fn );
    return this;
}
```

`this.context` is `document` (the default context as you did not give any context) and `this.selector` is `'.delete_message-link-js'` for the above example.

Comment: you are wrong . don't u look below [`that page`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)? -1

`$("p").on("click", function(){
alert( $(this).text() );`
});

Comment: @Esailija : you are using basic way, which is always right.
see this :http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/ncYJj/1/

Comment: @diEcho the whole point is that the element is added after the handler, that alerts "Esailija is right" as well anyway. It is not basic way, it is a "live" handler while your's is a "static" handler, which is viewed as the basic way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the `.on()` to the parent of the item:

```
// Pseudocode...
$('#parent of .delete_message-link-js').on('click', '.delete_message-link-js', false );
```